# Is L(K4) graph planar?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I'm a little confused with L(K4) [Line-Graph]

I had a text where L(K4) is not planar. Today I found this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g2na.png

So is L(K4) planar?

Thanks

Comment: Yes - the picture you link to shows that.   Perhaps you misread the text. Please [edit] the question to show us the actual assertion.

Comment: Which book do you use?

Answer (score 1):

$K_4$ is a graph on $4$ vertices and 6 edges. The line graph of $K_4$ is a 4-regular graph on 6 vertices as illustrated below:

It has a planar drawing(Hence planar):

[image]

[image]